# Bash script throwing syntax error near unexpected token `(' error

Tags: bash

The following script

```
jq -r '.[] | $(echo .key | awk -v stg="$STAGE" '{  gsub("/"stg"/COMMON/", "", $0); gsub("/", "_", $0); print $0 })' + "=\"" + (.value|tostring) + "\""' tmp_common_params > tmp_common_params_cleaned
```

is giving error though

```
$(echo .key | awk -v stg="$STAGE" '{  gsub("/"stg"/COMMON/", "", $0); gsub("/", "_", $0); print $0 })
```

works individually

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: Even in the expression that 'works' I can see only one single quote (`'`).

Comment: hey not understanding can you explain

Comment: Can you show the value of `$STAGE` and what you want to find with `echo .key | awk -v stg="$STAGE" '{  gsub("/"stg"/COMMON/", "", $0); gsub("/", "_", $0); print $0 }` ? I think this can be replaced by a very simple command, avoiding mistakes ith single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one `'` at the end of this line, right after the last curly bracket and before the last parentheses:

```
> $(echo .key | awk -v stg="$STAGE" '{  gsub("/"stg"/COMMON/", "", $0); gsub("/", "_", $0); print $0 })
```

Try adding it and test again.

Also, you may find useful this tool for that kind of debugging: https://www.shellcheck.net/